# Refresh a view Android

Tags: java, android

I want to refresh a listview. When I am getting a value from different class I want it to update that to list view. I am creating a thread for refreshing the list but I am getting an exception:

`Only the original thread that created a thread a view hierarchy can touch its views`

How to proceed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of trying to refresh the view to update the list just take the Adapter object and call the notifyDataSetChanged() API.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you work with multiple threads in an Android GUI you should use [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)s. The Android Dev Guide has a good example of how to use `Handler`s with a `ProgressDialog` when you expand the subsection *Example ProgressDialog with a second thread* [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog).

The example should be easy to understand and help you to apply the same concept to your list view.

Comment: Also, see this similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280141/android-calledfromwrongthreadexception-only-the-original-thread-that-created