# CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch views

Tags: android, handler, android-asynctask

I have an issue with the following error in Android:

> CalledFromWrongThreadException;: Only
>   the original thread that created a
>   view hierarchy can touch its views

It appears to happen when I try to update a Textview in my Activity, the call to update the TextView is from within my Activity but I still get the above error.

I have it like this:

onCreate()
-sets up the buttons and the text view.

onStateChange() - a listener for notifications about state changes, when this gets notification if changes the TextView to say some different text.

When I get notification of a new text I try to change the TextView as so:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.title)).setText("Some Text");
```

But I get the above Error.

From googling it, it appears I should use a handler to change the TextView or maybe use AsyncTask?

Could anyone explain which one would be better to use and why?

**EDIT: ADDED CODE SNIPPETS:**

---

```
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);  

            setContentView(R.layout.my);

            getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.my_title);  

            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.time)).setText("Hello Text");


            findViewById(R.id.keyboardimage).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent dialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:"));
                    startActivity(dialIntent);

                        dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.FLAG_SOFT_KEYBOARD));
                        dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));       
                }
        });

     }
```

---

```
//CallBacks from running Service

private final ICallDialogActivity.Stub iCallDialogActivity = new ICallDialogActivity.Stub(){

@Override
public void onStateChanged(int callState)
                throws RemoteException {    
            switch(callState){
            case GlobalData.CALL_STATUS_IDLE:

                break;

            case GlobalData.CALL_STATUS_DISCONNECTING:
                byeSetup();
                break;
    } 

};
```

---

```
public void byeSetup(){

            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.time)).setText("Bye Text");

            findViewById(R.id.keyboardimage).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Void the Button
                }});
}
```

Comment: are you in a subclass? onStateChange is overridden where?

Comment: Hi Pentium10, it is overridden via an AIDL interface and communicates with a Service, the Service will get notified of some change and will then tell the Activity to update its TextView based on that. I have added code snippets to better demonstrate what I am attempting, The error seems to appear very randomly and appears both when the Activity is in the foreground and is not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CalledFromWrongThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413544/calledfromwrongthreadexception)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Look like you are on the wrong thread. Try using a Handler to update the GUI on the right thread. See [Handling Expensive Operations in the UI Thread](http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#threading) example from android.com. Basically you would wrap `byeSetup` in a `Runnable` and invoke it with a `Handler` instance.

```
Handler refresh = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
refresh.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run()
    {
        byeSetup();
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks like I dont have to kill me. *Phew*

Comment: I think Keshav's answer is better.

Comment: Is this better than using `runOnUiThread()`? I can see that we don't need a reference to the Activity. Are there other advantages of this solution?

Answer (score 7):

when the change involves to the main thread (**UiThread**). Use it inside of another Thread to changes any view.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

      // TODO your Code 
        et_Pass.setText("");
    }
});
```

Comment: This should be the acceptable answer, if you are using Fragment, you can call this method by getActivity.runOnUiThread()......

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on willcodejavaforfood's answer for clarity & implementation...

I got this to work and below is how I did it.  I'm running multiple processing threads in a Service so other solutions that run in Activity don't work, like runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {}...

Put this at the top of your service class so it's accessible everywhere in this class:

```
Handler handler;
```

Put this in your service class onCreate method or something that loads on Service main thread

```
handler= new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

Put this inside your additional thread to 'post back' code to get run in UI or service UI (whatevers its called):

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        playNext(); //or whatever method you want to call thats currently not working
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For others, just replace byeSetup(); with your code statements or methods. byeSetup() is a sample method. Hope it will save some of your time.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, this time making use of `android.os.Message`

Have `android.os.Handler` defined as a field within your activity:

```
private final Handler myTextHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message stringMessage) {
        textView.append((String) stringMessage.obj);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Then feed it from your other thread like this:

```
Message stringMessage = Message.obtain(myTextHandler);
stringMessage.obj = "Hello!";
stringMessage.sendToTarget();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use view's inbuilt post method to update contents in other thread like I'm using edit text in kotlin.

```
address_box.post { address_box.text="my text"}
```