# CalledFromWrongThreadException

Tags: android

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final ThraedDemo objDemo = new ThraedDemo();
    Thread objThread = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            objDemo.firstMethod();
        }
    };
    objThread.start();
}


class ThraedDemo {

        private void firstMethod() {
            Thread objThread = new Thread() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageViewnumber)).setImageResource(nums[n]);

                        Thread.sleep(10000);
                        Log.v("Thread","1111111111111111sleep");
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        System.out.println("interuped exception" + ex.getMessage());
                    }
                    secondMethod();
                }

                private void secondMethod() {
        Thread objThread = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageViewResult)).setImageResource(nums[n+1]);

                n++;

                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                   Log.v("Thread","22222222222 sleep");
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    System.out.println("interuped exception" + ex.getMessage());
                }
                firstMethod();
            }
        };
        objThread.start();
    }

            };
            objThread.start();
        }

    }
```

I use the above code but it is not running.it got `CalledFromWrongThreadException` what is the problem  inb the above code.Please give me some suggestions.Thanks in advance

Comment: Use [Bolts-Android](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android) for threading in android

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you can't do view modifications from another thread than the UI thread, so either create [handlers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) in the oncreate and post your thread to it, or use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), or [runOnUIThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method to send portions of code directly to the UI thread.

Comment: If you want your 2 threads to be executed one after the other, why not simply post your 2 threads to the same handler?

Comment: "Related to your question" - what is your question then? I thought that Sephy gave an appropriate answer to your only question in text. Be more specific.

Comment: Thank u for your response Sephy, and  how we use the  2 threads in handlers.Give me some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I edited your 2nd function code,  I see your code is loop forever cause the firstMethod call secondMethod and the secondMethod call the new firstMethod to start and then loop forever. I removed it and moved the code update ImageView into the UI Thread, could you try this:

```
class ThraedDemo {

    private void firstMethod() {
        Thread objThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run(){ 
                            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageViewnumber)).setImageResource(nums[n]);  
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    Log.v("Thread","1111111111111111sleep");
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    System.out.println("interuped exception" + ex.getMessage());
                }
                secondMethod();
            }
        };
        objThread.start();
    }

    private void secondMethod() {
        Thread objThread2 = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run(){ 
                            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageViewnumber)).setImageResource(nums[n+1]);  
                        }
                    });
                    n++;
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    Log.v("Thread","22222222222 sleep");
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    System.out.println("interuped exception" + ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        };
        objThread2.start();
    }
}
```