# android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException : Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm developing an Android application and I'm using Eclipse as IDE and my database is     MySQL. I have the follow problem. When I try to take datas from the database through the AsynTask I have the error that I show below.

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException:
Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy 
can touch its views
```

Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   asyn=new MyAsyncTask();

   tvtexto=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvtextoMa);
   context = getApplicationContext();
   eventos = new ArrayList<Eventos>();
   eventosAdapter = new EventosAdapter(context, R.layout.filae, eventos);
   eventos=new ArrayList<Eventos>();
   asyn.execute();
   listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01Ma);
}
```

AsyncTask:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
{
   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) 
   {
      eventos=(ArrayList<Eventos>) BDEventos.getDatosEventos();
      for(Eventos n:eventos){
         eventosAdapter.add(n);
      }
      eventosAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      listView.setAdapter(eventosAdapter);
      return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: You will find a lot of answers to your problem searching for '[android] CalledFromWrongThreadException'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CalledFromWrongThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413544/calledfromwrongthreadexception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating ui from background thread is not possible. `doInbackground is invoked on the background thread. Ui should be updated on the ui thread.

Get your data form data base in `doInbackground` return result and update ui accordingly in `onPostExecute`.

```
eventosAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
listView.setAdapter(eventosAdapter);
```

SHould be in `onPostExecute`