# android - Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException

Tags: android, web-services, textview

I'm trying to get username and user ID from web service and I try to change his value depend on value I got it from server, When I try to change textview value outside onCreate function I have this error:

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

**Profile.java**

```
public class Profile extends Activity {

    TextView mymoUserName;
    TextView mymoID;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);      

        setContentView(R.layout.profile);

        getActionBar().hide();

        mymoUserName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.profMymoUserName);
        mymoID = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.profMymoID);

        getUserInfo();

    }

    protected void getUserInfo() 
    {
        Thread t = new Thread() {

            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare();
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000);
                HttpResponse response;

                String URL = "MY_URL";

                try {
                        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);

                        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("section", "API" ));

                        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                        response = client.execute(post);

                        if(response!=null)
                        {
                            String res = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                            JSONObject result = new JSONObject(res);

                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), res , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            String username = result.getString("username");
                            mymoUserName.setText(username);

                            String mymoId = result.getString("mymo_id");
                            mymoID.setText(mymoId);

                        }

                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                Looper.loop();
            }
        };

        t.start();      
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
    {
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: It's semi-self-explanatory. And [searching](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+CalledFromWrongThreadException) gives you the rest.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CalledFromWrongThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413544/calledfromwrongthreadexception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are updating ui from a thread. You should update ui from ui thread only

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), res , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
mymoUserName.setText(username);
mymoID.setText(mymoId);
```

must be in ui thread.

You can use `runOnUiThread`.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
         String res = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
         JSONObject result = new JSONObject(res);
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), res , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         String username = result.getString("username");
         mymoUserName.setText(username);

         String mymoId = result.getString("mymo_id");
         mymoID.setText(mymoId);

}
});
```

But you should consider using `AsyncTask`. You can do your background operation in `doInBackground` update ui `onPreExecute`, `onPostExecute` and `onProgressUpdate`

Comment: Sorry but I'm new on android can you explain more :(

Comment: @Abutouq about which topic should i expand.

Comment: How i should use runOnUiThread what i should remove form my code!

Answer (score 0):

You can access UI through android UI thread only.
Add UI accessing statements in runOnUiThread as follows..

```
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), res , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            String username = result.getString("username");
            mymoUserName.setText(username);

            String mymoId = result.getString("mymo_id");
            mymoID.setText(mymoId);
        }
    });
```