# CalledFromWrongThreadException when trying to disable button

Tags: android

I'm getting this error:

```
10-06 09:09:25.466: 
E/not work(1300):
pass exceptionandroid.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

my Android project pass above error when i am try to disabled button.

```
if (success == 1) {
    Log.i("enable", "working//////");
    upload.setEnabled(true);
    sendDeseaseDetails.setEnabled(false);
}else{
    upload.setActivated(false);
    sendDeseaseDetails.setEnabled(true);
}
```

above code run time pass this error. what is wrong........? please help me...........!

This is full code:

```
package viewActivity;

//import java.io.Externalizable;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.src.adms.R;

import controller.DBConnection;
//import android.R.string;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.text.Editable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public class Send_deases_Detail extends Activity {

    Spinner diseaseSpinner; // disease type
    Spinner weatherSpinner; // get weather
    Spinner districSpinner; // get district
    Spinner soilConditionSpinner; // get soil condition

    ImageButton upload; // upload images
    Button clear; // clear field
    Button sendDeseaseDetails; // button send disease details

    int success = 0; // use, to know disease details send successfully

    private Bundle extraslogin; // to get username and password

    private String userName;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private String password;
    private String userType;
    private int deases_id;
    private String diseaseType;
    private String weather;
    private String soilCondition;
    private String district;

    private EditText plantName;
    private EditText region;
    private EditText userDescription;

    private static final String SEND_DESEASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:80/ADMS/andrioidConnection/send_deases_detail.php";
    // private static final String SEND_DESEASE_URL
    // ="http://admstest.netau.net/ADMS/andrioidConnection/send_deases_detail.php";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
    private static final String TAG_USER_TYPE = "usertype";
    private static final String TAG_DEASES_ID = "deases_id";

    DBConnection dbConnection = new DBConnection();

    private ProgressDialog dialogBox;

    // private Object EditText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.deases_detail);

        // get user name and password form LoIin
        extraslogin = getIntent().getExtras();
        userName = extraslogin.getString("user_name");
        password = extraslogin.getString("pass_word");

        plantName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPlantName);
        diseaseSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.diseaseTypeSpinner);
        weatherSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.weather_Spinner);
        districSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.district_Spinner);
        soilConditionSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.soil_condition_Spinner);

        // get id of image upload button
        upload = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebtUpload);
        //upload.setEnabled(false); // default set false

        // get date
        // ...................................................................................
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "d/M/yy h:m:s a");
        String stringDate = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
        textView.setText(stringDate);

        // this for disease type spinner
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> diseasearrArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter
                .createFromResource(this, R.array.diseaseType_array,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        diseasearrArrayAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        diseaseSpinner.setAdapter(diseasearrArrayAdapter);
        diseaseSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(15);
                // get selected item
                diseaseType = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }

        });

        // this for weather type spinner
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> weatherArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter
                .createFromResource(this, R.array.weather_array,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        weatherArrayAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        weatherSpinner.setAdapter(weatherArrayAdapter);
        weatherSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(15);
                // to get selected item
                weather = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        // this for district spinner
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> districArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter
                .createFromResource(this, R.array.district_array,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        districArrayAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        districSpinner.setAdapter(districArrayAdapter);
        districSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(15);
                // get selected item
                district = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        // this for soil
        // condition..........................................................................................................

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> soilArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter
                .createFromResource(this, R.array.soil_array,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        soilArrayAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        soilConditionSpinner.setAdapter(soilArrayAdapter);
        soilConditionSpinner
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                            View view, int position, long id) {

                        ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(15);
                        // to get selected item
                        soilCondition = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });

        // ..............................................................................

        region = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editRegion);
        userDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editDescription);

        // give action to send disease details
        // button........................................................
        sendDeseaseDetails = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btSendDetails);
        sendDeseaseDetails.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new sendDetail().execute();
            }
        });
        // ..............................................................................

        // give action to cancel
        // button...................................................................
        clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btCancel);
        clear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clear();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "clear field",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            private void clear() {
                plantName.setText("");
                region.setText("");
                userDescription.setText("");
                upload.setEnabled(false);
                sendDeseaseDetails.setEnabled(true);
                weatherSpinner.setSelection(0);
                soilConditionSpinner.setSelection(0);
                districSpinner.setSelection(0);
                diseaseSpinner.setSelection(0);
                configureImageUploadButton();


            }
        });

        clear.performClick();

    }

    // configure Image Upload Button......................................

    private void configureImageUploadButton() {

        // upload.setEnabled(true);
        upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "click image button",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // pass data to image Take activity
                Intent imageTakeActivity = new Intent(Send_deases_Detail.this,
                        ImageTakeActivity.class);
                imageTakeActivity.putExtra("user_type", userType);
                imageTakeActivity.putExtra("deases_id", deases_id);

                success=0;
                //enable();


                // go to ImageTakeActivity
                startActivity(imageTakeActivity);
                finish();

            }
        });

    }

    // .................................................................................

    protected void enable() {
        if (success == 1) {
            Log.i("enable", "working//////");
            upload.setEnabled(true);
            sendDeseaseDetails.setEnabled(false);
        }else{
            upload.setEnabled(false);
            sendDeseaseDetails.setEnabled(true);
        }


    }

    class sendDetail extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        // preprocessing part

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialogBox = new ProgressDialog(Send_deases_Detail.this);
            dialogBox.setTitle("Processing...");
            dialogBox.setMessage("Please wait...");
            dialogBox.setIndeterminate(false);
            dialogBox.setCancelable(true);
            dialogBox.show();
        }

        // back ground run process
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            String plant_name = plantName.getText().toString();
            String region_name = region.getText().toString();
            String user_discription = userDescription.getText().toString();

            try {
                // add first name, last name, Email & password to array list
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_name", userName));
                // params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass_word", password));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("disease_type", diseaseType));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("weather", weather));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("soil_condition",
                        soilCondition));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("district", district));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("plant_name", plant_name));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("region _name", region_name));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_discription",
                        user_discription));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = dbConnection.createHttpRequest(
                        SEND_DESEASE_URL, "POST", params);

                // check your register for json response
                Log.d("Send detail  attempt", json.toString());

                // json success tag

                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                deases_id = json.getInt(TAG_DEASES_ID);
                userType = json.getString(TAG_USER_TYPE);
                Log.d("deases_id", String.valueOf(deases_id));

                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Send Desease Detaiail Successful!", json.toString());

                    //configureImageUploadButton();//comment

                    Log.i("after!", "???pass configureImageUploadButton");

                    // configureImageUploadButton();
                    // finish();
                    // startActivity(i);
                    try {
                            enable(); // call to image button enable method
                        //finish();
                    } catch (Exception exception) {
                        Log.e("not work", "pass exception"+exception);
                    }

                    Log.i("work", "in back ground process......");
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    Log.d("Send detail fail!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            dialogBox.dismiss();
            if (result != null) {
                Toast.makeText(Send_deases_Detail.this, result,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

please help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [CalledFromWrongThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413544/calledfromwrongthreadexception)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In android you need to perform any actions on views from the main UI thread. This post [Running code in main thread from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123621/running-code-in-main-thread-from-another-thread) will give you an idea of how to do so.