# Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views [2]

Tags: android, kotlin

When I try to start the app, after one second the app crash and this appear in the LOGCAT:

```
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

What I was expecting: When app opens, it shows the hour, minutes and seconds of the device and update it forever per second

Code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Timer().schedule(object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                val textView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.dateAndTime)
                val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss z")
                val currentDateAndTime: String = simpleDateFormat.format(Date())
                textView.text = currentDateAndTime
            }
        }, 1000)
    }

}
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413544/calledfromwrongthreadexception

Comment: I'm thinking that your link is about Java, not Kotlin. @lukas.j

Comment: Thread associated with Timer is background. And from background thread you are trying to access main thread UI elements hence this is giving this error

Comment: @Luiz: it is about Android. You cannot modify a View from any thread but the UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timer thread runs on a different thread than the views

Change your code to this

```
val textView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.dateAndTime)

Timer().schedule(object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
              
                val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss z")
                val currentDateAndTime: String = simpleDateFormat.format(Date())

//This does the trick
runOnUiThread{
                textView.text = currentDateAndTime
}
            }
        }, 1000)
```

Comment: For some reason, the text was not edited, but there are no errors now.

Comment: You can try logging currentDateAndTime and see if it's changing