# Libgdx: Application crashes with CalledFromWrongThreadException exception when GestureDetector tries to change screen brightness

Tags: android, libgdx, window-managers, gesturedetector

I have a libgdx project in Android studio. In the AndroidLauncher class i am starting a ApplicationAdapter called ClockActivity and also registering a GuestureDetector.

```
    public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        ClockActivity clockActivity = new ClockActivity();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new GestureDetector(new GestureHandler()));

    }


class GestureHandler implements GestureDetector.GestureListener {

            @Override
        public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {

            WindowManager.LayoutParams layout;

            Gdx.app.log("LOG:", "pan" + deltaY);

            layout = getWindow().getAttributes();
            float currentValue = layout.screenBrightness;
            layout.screenBrightness = currentValue - 10;
            getWindow().setAttributes(layout);
            return false;
        }


}
}
```

The ClockActivity extends ApplicationAdapter class and its job is to display current system time on screen.

```
public class ClockActivity extends ApplicationAdapter {
@Override
public void create () {
    Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(true);
}
@Override
public void render() {
    // my job is to display time
}
}
```

When i run on my Android phone and I try to pan hoping to adjust the brightness. However, application crashes with the following exception.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 42617
              Process: com.mygdx.clock, PID: 25614
              android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6293)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:900)
                  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17378)
                  at android.view.View.setLayoutParams(View.java:11373)
                  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.updateViewLayout(WindowManagerGlobal.java:302)
                  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.updateViewLayout(WindowManagerImpl.java:74)
                  at android.app.Activity.onWindowAttributesChanged(Activity.java:2608)
                  at android.view.Window.dispatchWindowAttributesChanged(Window.java:832)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.dispatchWindowAttributesChanged(PhoneWindow.java:3879)
                  at android.view.Window.setAttributes(Window.java:863)
                  at com.mygdx.clock.AndroidLauncher$GestureHandler.pan(AndroidLauncher.java:99)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.input.GestureDetector.touchDragged(GestureDetector.java:159)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.input.GestureDetector.touchDragged(GestureDetector.java:126)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput.processEvents(AndroidInput.java:382)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:457)
                  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1522)
                  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239)
```

I am not able to understand the CalledFromWrongThreadException error. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3281046/1261394). Inside your `pan` method, you cannot do anything with your layout, since (I think) it is called from the GDX thread, and not the Android thread. You will have to use a handler to execute the layout code on the Android thread.

Maybe try something like this:

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
private final Runnable panUI = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        layout = getWindow().getAttributes();
        float currentValue = layout.screenBrightness;
        layout.screenBrightness = currentValue - 10;
        getWindow().setAttributes(layout);
    }
};
```

Now in your pan method:

```
public boolean pan(float x, ...) {
    handler.post(panUI);
    return false;
}
```