# Application skipping frames

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, navigation-drawer

I have an navigation drawer Activity in which I have made 3 fragments using ViewPager. Each of the fragment has an edit Text, Image button and RecyclerView. The RecyclerView is getting data from a local SQLite database.

**On opening the app, I get a Log trace that application skipped XX frames.**
(Usually 30-50 frames). Is it normal ? 
If not, then what should I do? Can fragments be made using background thread like AsyncTask? Or should I populate RecyclerView in background thread?

Comment: do you use SQLite on the main thread?

Comment: use `LoaderManager` to load content

Comment: The application is doing too much work in the main thread. move DB operations and other costly operations to background thread

Comment: @ZUNJAE yes I am.

Comment: @SarathKn background thread like AsyncTask or is there something else also?

Comment: Don't do that then

Comment: @RahulKumar LoaderManager is deprecated in API 28

Comment: every action which performs reads or writes, or that is longer than 16 ms which doesn't require a UI update should be done in a background thread to prevent the app from freezing.

Comment: @ZUNJAE won't I need to write the data on UI thread?

Comment: no? Why would you?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it normal?

Nope. Check out [Choreographer](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/Choreographer.java) (start at line 619) if you are eager to find out what's happening behind the scenes.

> what should I do?  Can fragments be made using background thread like AsyncTask?

You can't do anything with `Views` on a background Thread since that would cause a [CalledFromWrongThreadException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280141/calledfromwrongthreadexception-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hie), but what you definitely can and should do is *moving all performance-heavy operations like DB read/write* to worker Threads. Check out the [AsyncTask and AsyncTaskLoader](https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts/content/en/Unit%203/71c_asynctask_and_asynctaskloader_md.html) chapter from "Android Developer Fundamentals Course", it will give you a good start on background processing.

Also note that the [LoaderManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/LoaderManager) from the support library is **not** deprecated.